# Converting a working code from double-precision to quadruple-precision: How to read quadruple-precision numbers in FORTRAN from an input file

Tags: gcc, input, fortran, runtime-error, scientific-notation

I have a big, old, FORTRAN 77 code that has worked for many, many years with no problems.
Double-precision is not enough anymore, so to convert to quadruple-precision I have:

1. Replaced all occurrences of `REAL*8` to `REAL*16`
2. Replaced all functions like DCOS() into functions like COS()
3. Replaced all built-in numbers like 0.d0 to 0.q0 , and 1D+01 to 1Q+01

The program compiles with no errors or warnings with the gcc-4.6 compiler on

1. operating system: openSUSE 11.3 x86_64 (a 64-bit operating system)
2. hardware: Intel Xeon E5-2650 (Sandy Bridge)

My LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is set to the 64-bit library folder:
/gcc-4.6/lib64

The program reads an input file that has numbers in it.
Those numbers used to be of the form 1.234D+02 (for the double-precision version of the code, which works).
I have changed them so now that number is 1.234Q+02 , however I get the runtime error:

**Bad real number in item 1 of list input**

Indicating that the subroutine that reads in the data from the input file (called *read.f*) does not find the first number in the inputfile, to be compatible with what it expected.

Strangely, the quadruple-precision version of the code does *not* complain when the input file contains numbers like 1.234D+02 or 123.4 (which, based on the output seems to automatically be converted to the form 1.234D+02 rather than Q+02), it just does not like the Q+02 , so it seems that gcc-4.6 does not allow quadruple-precision numbers to be read in from input files in scientific notation !

**Has anyone ever been able to read from an input file a quadruple-precision number in scientific notation (ie, like 1234Q+02) in FORTRAN with a gcc compiler, and if so how did you get it to work ? (or did you need a different compiler/operating system/hardware to get it to work ?)**

Comment: You appear to be conflating the text representation of a real of particular kind in source with the text representation of real data in an input file.  There is no need to have a different exponent character in the input file - just use E.  The Fortran processor (here represented by your compiler's runtime libraries) will convert that text representation in the input file into whatever appropriate internal representation the program uses.

Comment: This exactly the kind of problems where you should employ the kind notation (`real(wp)` and `1._wp`). You then just adjust `wp` in the top module to whatever you currently need.

Comment: Thanks @IanH ! I changed all Q's to D's in the input file and the program runs. I left the question up because I still want my program to be able to read in 12Q+01 since my input files are generated by another program. Is it also possible for me to leave all hardcoded numbers like 1.234D+02 in the actual .f files, as D+02 instead of Q+02, and rely on the compiler to convert them to quadruple-precision based on the fact that their respective variables are REAL*16 ? I would really like to just have one code with #define controlling the choice of REAL*8 and REAL*16, and no other changes.

Comment: After such a long time you should really ask a new question instead. You have a couple of syntax errors there.

Comment: I thought I followed M.S.B.'s instructions properly. What are the syntax errors?

Comment: No, ask a new question.

Comment: you really need to start a new question, but i,ll ask here are your "quad precision" input files *really* quad precision, ie. like 30+ decimal digits?

Comment: @VladimirF: In response to your request, I have started a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415703/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-in-fortran-how-do-i-declare-the-precision-of-a-n. I just worry about getting voted down for it, because really it is just a question about how to implement M. S. B.'s suggestion in his/her answer to this question. I just can't get a simple version of his suggestion to compile (he suggested to put "use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV" and "WP = real128" between "program" and "implicit none". That's what I did. Then I declared the variables exactly as M. S. B. showed

Comment: @agentp: Your thinking is right. The input files contain some simple numbers such as 1.234Q+02. The suggestion of IanH to turn all exponents in the input file form (D or Q) to E, was successful. My input file now only contains exponents defined by E instead of by D or Q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost all of this is already in comments by @IanH and @Vladimi.

I suggest mixing in a little Fortran 90 into your FORTRAN 77 code.

Write all of your numbers with "E".   Change your other program to write the data this way.  Don't bother with "D" and don't try to use the infrequently supported "Q".  (Using "Q" in constants in source code is an extension of gfortran -- see 6.1.8 in manual.)

Since you want the same source code to support two precisions, at the top of the program, have:

```
use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
WP = real128
```

or

```
use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
WP = real64
```

as the variation that changes whether your code is using double or quadruple precision.  This is using the ISO Fortran Environment to select the types by their number of bits.  (`use` needs to between `program` and `implicit none`; the assignment statement after `implicit none`.)

Then declare your real variables via:

```
real (WP) :: MyVar
```

In source code, write real constants as `1.23456789012345E+12_WP`.  The `_type` is the Fortran 90 way of specifying the type of a constant.  This way you can go back and forth between double and quadruple precision by only changing the single line defining `WP`

WP == Working Precision.

Just use "E" in input files.   Fortran will read according to the type of the variable.

Why not write a tiny test program to try it out?

Comment: Dear M. S. B., I tried a very simple code (see extension at the bottom of my original question). It gives errors at compile time. Can you please give us a minimum working example ?