# How do I declare the precision of a number to be an adjustable parameter?

Tags: gcc, fortran, precision, gfortran, arbitrary-precision

In 2013 there was a question on converting a big working code from double to quadruple precision: "[Converting a working code from double-precision to quadruple-precision: How to read quadruple-precision numbers in FORTRAN from an input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137127/converting-a-working-code-from-double-precision-to-quadruple-precision-how-to-r)", and the consensus was to declare variables using an adjustable parameter "WP" that specifies the "working precision", instead of having a separate version of the program with variables declared using D+01, and another version using Q+01. This way we can easily switch back and forth by defining WP=real128 or WP=real64 at the top, and the rest doesn't need to change.

But how do we do this?

I tried the suggestion in the answer to that question, by making a simple code TEST.F90:

```
  PROGRAM TEST
  use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
  WP= real128
  IMPLICIT NONE
  real (WP) ::  X
  X= 5.4857990945E-4_WP
  END PROGRAM TEST
```

compiled with:

```
~/gcc-4.6/bin/gfortran -o tst.x TEST.F90
```

But it gives:

```
      IMPLICIT NONE
                   1
Error: Unexpected IMPLICIT NONE statement at (1)
QLEVEL16.F90:5.12:

      real (WP) ::  MEL 
            1
Error: Parameter 'wp' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
QLEVEL16.F90:6.29:

      MEL= 5.4857990945E-4_WP
                             1
Error: Missing kind-parameter at (1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kind specifier must be an integer parameter - and you do not declare it appropriately. Furthermore, `implicit none` must go before any declaration.

Here is a working version addressing both issues:

```
PROGRAM TEST
  use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
  IMPLICIT NONE
  integer, parameter :: WP= real128
  real (WP) ::  X

  X= 5.4857990945E-4_WP
END PROGRAM TEST
```

Comment: Excellent! The answer in the other thread made it seem that WP=real128 should be right after use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, and did not show the "integer, parameter ::" part.  That was the source of my problem. Thank you!

Comment: It's perhaps more tempting to have `use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, wp=>real128`, no?

Comment: Thank you @francescalus. What are the advantages and disadvantages of the two alternative options?

Comment: @user1271772, to be fair they have much the same impact.  My suggested version is possibly closer to the intent as you have it in the question (ie., part of the using).  It's essentially saying "take the value `real128` from the module but call it `wp` here".  The other is "have a new constant `wp` which has the same value as `real128` from the module".  If you want still to refer to `real128` you'll want the second approach.

Comment: In my codes, I prefer to use the constants from `ISO_Fortran_env` directly, i.e. `real(REAL128) :: ...` and `1.0_REAL128`. That makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Actually many code using this WP approach. Many with select_*_kind intrinsic function. But I think there is a 'easier' way. It's to use default precision without specifying any kind keyword andusing compiler's flag to choose what the default precision is.

Pro is this method is easier if you don't need a precise control of precision on each variable. Con is that will heavily depend on compiler flags, which  varies for each compiler or even might not available.

For gfortran, there is more flags `-freal4-real8` or `-freal4-real16` to promote each explicitly specified lower precision variable to higher precision.

Comment: This is actually the preferred approach I think. But I don't know how to do it.